# $( \mathscr{X}, d_x)$ and $( \mathscr{Y}, d_y)$ metric spaces ..Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Let
$( \mathscr{X}, d_x)$ and $( \mathscr{Y}, d_y)$  be two metric spaces and

$ D \subset \mathscr{X} $ a compact set.

To show is, that if

$f: D \rightarrow \mathscr{Y} $is continous and injective, then

$ f^{-1} :f(D) \rightarrow D $

is also continous.

My Idea:

Since $D$ is compact, it is also closed.
$$ (f^{-1})^{-1} (D)= f(D) $$
And since $f$ is continous and $D$ compact, is also $f(D)$ compact.
As Subset of the metric space $\mathscr{Y} $ is $f(D)$ also closed.
So the inverse image of a closed image is also closed, therefore is $f^{-1}$ is also continous.

Does that makes sense to you? :)
but where does the injectivity comes in?
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: What do you mean by “completed”? Do you mean “closed”?

Comment: yes, I edited it

Comment: Your proof is correct. If $f$ was not injective, then $f^{-1}$ would not exist.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The proof **is not** correct at all. He needs to verify the condition for any closed subset of $D$, not just $D$ itself.

Comment: @Federico, how do I do that?

Comment: You have $g=f^{-1}:f(D)\to D$. To show that $g$ is continuous, you have to take an arbitrary closed set $E\subset D$ and go from there...

Comment: @Federico But $D$ is an arbitrary compact subset of $\mathscr{X}$. And, since $\mathscr{X}$ is compact, $D$ is an arbitrary closed subset of $\mathscr{X}$. So, the OP proved that $f$ is a closed map. This is equivalent to the assertion that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The space $X$ is not compact. $D$ is the domain of $f$, not a generic subset

Comment: @Federico I see! You are right then.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=f^{-1}:f(D)\to D$. We show that $g$ is continuous if $g^{-1}(E)$ is closed for every $E\subset D$ closed.

Fix $E\subset D$ closed. Since $D$ is compact, $E$ is also compact. Therefore $g^{-1}(E)=f(E)$ is compact, hence closed.

Notice that the proof holds for every $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. No need for a metric structure.